# Data always go to the same parameters in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

For my chatbot if user say "most" it will go to parameter "ansQ1_3", "little" will go to parameter "ansQ1_1" and "none" will go to parameter "ansQ1_0" but when i answer any words it will go to parameter "ansQ1_0" and data doesn't change because every words will go to parameter "ansQ1_0" So, how can i fix this problem? Here is my code.

```
'use strict';
 
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

// initialise DB connection
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  databaseURL: 'ws://reliever-gkkdtw.firebaseio.com/',
});

const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; 
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  var test = "";
  var stressQ1 = 0;var stressQ2 = 0;var stressQ3 = 0;var stressQ4 = 0;var stressQ5 = 0;
  var answerDB = admin.database().ref();
  
  function answer1(agent) {
    
    if(agent.parameters.ansQ1_0 != ""){ 
      stressQ1 = 0;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ1_1 != ""){
        stressQ1 = 1;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ1_2 != ""){
        stressQ1 = 2;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ1_3 != ""){
        stressQ1 = 3;
    //}else{
    //      stressQ1 = 0;
    }
    //stressQ1 = stressQ1 + agent.parameters.numStressQ1;

    return answerDB.update({answer_1: stressQ1});                                                               
  }
  
  function answer2(agent) {
    
    if(agent.parameters.ansQ2_0 != ""){ 
      stressQ2 = 0;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ2_1 != ""){
        stressQ2 = 1;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ2_2 != ""){
        stressQ2 = 2;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ2_3 != ""){
        stressQ2 = 3;
    //}else{
    //      stressQ2 = 0;
    }

    return answerDB.update({answer_2: stressQ2});
  }
  
  function answer3(agent) {
    
    if(agent.parameters.ansQ3_0 != ""){ 
      stressQ3 = 0;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ3_1 != ""){
        stressQ3 = 1;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ3_2 != ""){
        stressQ3 = 2;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ3_3 != ""){
        stressQ3 = 3;
    //}else{
    //      stressQ3 = 0;
    }
    
    return answerDB.update({answer_3: stressQ3});
  }
  
  function answer4(agent) {
    
    if(agent.parameters.ansQ4_0 != ""){ 
      stressQ4 = 0;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ4_1 != ""){
        stressQ4 = 1;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ4_2 != ""){
        stressQ4 = 2;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ4_3 != ""){
        stressQ4 = 3;
    //}else{
    //      stressQ4 = 0;
    }
    
    return answerDB.update({answer_4: stressQ4});
  }
  
  function answer5(agent) {
    
    if(agent.parameters.ansQ5_0 != ""){ 
      stressQ5 = 0;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ5_1 != ""){
        stressQ5 = 1;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ5_2 != ""){
        stressQ5 = 2;
    }else if(agent.parameters.ansQ5_3 != ""){
        stressQ5 = 3;
    //}else{
    //      stressQ5 = 0;
    }
    
    agent.add('Thank you for answer the question, and you can go to reliever' +
              ' application to reduce the stress level');
    return answerDB.update({answer_5: stressQ5});
  }

  
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('askStressQ1',answer1);
  intentMap.set('askStressQ2',answer2);
  intentMap.set('askStressQ3',answer3);
  intentMap.set('askStressQ4',answer4);
  intentMap.set('askStressQ5',answer5);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

here is the problem on request.
[[all answer always go to parameter ansQ1_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8eK.png)]
[[all answer always go to parameter ansQ1_0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/356fD.png)]

and this is example of how i manage the answer about which answer will go to what parameter.

[[Training phrases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwVpr.png)]
[[action and parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piOFN.png)]

I already seperate every answer for each parameter but all answer always go to the ansQ1_0 parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a combination of two things (possibly compounded by a third):

1. All your parameters are of the same type.
2. All your training phrases are one word, of that type.

So there is no way for the training system to distinguish between when the user says a value intended for "ansQ1_0" or "ansQ1_1" for example.

When you specify a parameter for a training phrase, that parameter is expected to be able to take on any of the possible values for that type. The training phrase doesn't indicate what type you want.

Related to this, however is the third issue:

3. All the types are of `@sys.given-name`, which doesn't seem like it matches the training phrases you're trying to use. "Given name" talks about the name given to a person, and is a limited list of names.

I suspect you want to create [your own entity type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-custom) and set each parameter to a different type depending on what value you're expecting for each.

From here, you don't necessarily need to set it into five different parameters, however. From a quick glance at your code, you might just want to store it in one parameter and check which value was given by the user.